# DateFormat parse String with dateStyle and timeStyle

Tags: java

This code write on console

> ERROR: could not parse date in string "Nov 4, 2003 8:14 PM".

I don't understand why.

```
        String dateString = "Nov 4, 2003 8:14 PM";

    // Get the default MEDIUM/SHORT DateFormat
    DateFormat format =
            DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
                    DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.SHORT);

    // Parse the date
    try {
        Date date = format.parse(dateString);
        System.out.println("Original string: " + dateString);
        System.out.println("Parsed date    : " + date);
    }
    catch(ParseException pe) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: could not parse date in string \"" +
                dateString + "\"");
    }
```

Comment: On my PC, `DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.SHORT).format(new Date());` prints `14/10/2015 4:35 PM` , what does it print on yours?

Comment: Also, `DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.SHORT).format(new Date())` prints `14 October 2015 4:36 PM`, so I think you're going to have to use something like `SimpleDateFormat`, something like `DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy hh:mm a");` instead

Comment: I think u had importing wrong package for Date or some other class because I get the output on my system

Comment: what package you have import

Comment: i have import: import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Date;

Comment: The code above works fine on my environment. Output : <code>Original string: Nov 4, 2003 8:14 PM
Parsed date    : Tue Nov 04 20:14:00 EET 2003</code>;  Related imports are: <code>import java.util.Date;import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;</code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it states in documentation, the getDateTimeInstance(int dateStyle, int timeStyle) method gets the date/time formatter with the given date and time formatting styles for the default locale.

You have to pass the locale object too. Try to use the getDateTimeInstance(int dateStyle, int timeStyle, Locale aLocale) method.

Answer (score 0):

Better check your import libraries. I correct your error and give you a complete code.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Date;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         String dateString = "Nov 4, 2003 8:14 PM";

    // Get the default MEDIUM/SHORT DateFormat
    DateFormat format =
            DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
                    DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.SHORT);

    // Parse the date
    try {
        Date date = format.parse(dateString);
        System.out.println("Original string: " + dateString);
        System.out.println("Parsed date    : " + date);
    }
    catch(ParseException pe) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: could not parse date in string \"" +
                dateString + "\"");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you are getting error because of you have imported incorrect packages.
Try with importing below packages. It worked for me.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xpath.regex.ParseException;
```